# Prevent auto-save-list directory to be created

Tags: init-file

Although I have disable auto-save and auto-backups, the directory `auto-save-list` is still autodramatically created in my `.emacs.d` directory.

```
(setq backup-inhibited t
      make-backup-files nil
      auto-save-default nil)
```

How can I prevent it to be created ?

Comment: Have a look at the variable `auto-save-list-file-prefix` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto_002dSaving.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To dereference @lawlist's comment (link to http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto_002dSaving.html):

> User Option: auto-save-list-file-prefix
>
> After Emacs reads your init file, it initializes `auto-save-list-file-name` (if you have not already set it non-nil)
>   based on this prefix, adding the host name and process ID. If you set
>   this to `nil` in your init file, then Emacs does not initialize
>   `auto-save-list-file-name`.

You need to have an equivalent of the following in your init file:

```
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix nil)
```